# Split one word into two?

Tags: c#, split

lets say we have the input: "like"
the output should be: "li     ke".

i tried this method:

```
String mystring = TextBox1.Text;
String[] mysplit = mystring.Split(new Char[]{' ',','});
Label3.Text = mysplit[0];
Label5.Text = mysplit[1];
```

but this method will split if there is more than one word and there is either a space and colon between them. what i want is one word to be divided into two parts and be displayed in either one or two labels

Comment: What if your `mystring.Length` is odd number?

Answer (score 6):

Use [`String.SubString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
var length = str.Length;

var firstHalf = str.Substring(0, length / 2);
var secondHalf = str.Substring(length / 2, length - (length / 2));
```

If the string has an odd number of characters, the second half will have 1 more character than the first half.

If you want the first half to have 1 more character than the second half, do this instead:

```
var length = str.Length;
var half = (int) Math.Ceiling(length/2.0);

var firstHalf = str.Substring(0, half);
var secondHalf = str.Substring(half, length - half);
```

Comment: what if word length is 13char? it will round automatically?

Comment: @stackunderflow integer division will truncate the result, so the first half will have 6 characters and the second half 7 characters. I've added another code snippet that does the opposite, if necessary.