# New to programming - Would like to know how to take a word and split it into two portions

Tags: notepad++

I'm new to programming and I have been searching all over to try and find the answer.

I am trying to take my list of words I've made and split each of them into two fragments/portions. Example: Celebrate ---- Cele Brate

I found an article that I believe explains what to type, but I'm wondering how I would apply it to the list of words? Would Notepad++ work? And how would I go about doing that? Sorry, I'm EXTREMELY new to all of this... I just want to know how to input the code and have it run and apply it to that list.

Thanks for everything that you programmers do!

**Here is the article and code mentioned:**
[Split one word into two?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22594482/split-one-word-into-two?newreg=ebc447ef9b574291bcf635695e3e1628)

var length = str.Length;

var half = (int) Math.Ceiling(length/2.0);

var firstHalf = str.Substring(0, half);

var secondHalf = str.Substring(half, length - half);

Comment: "notepad++" isn't a language.

Comment: Notepad++ isn’t a language; it’s only a text editor. What language are you using? It looks like C#, and that’s the language in the question you linked to, but is that the language you’re looking for an answer for?

Comment: I believe it is c#. I just feel really helpless. So would I type in the code into Notepad++ then run a notepad such as Ted Notepad or just the Windows Notepad?

Comment: @JosuhaN No notepad I know of is capable of running code, especially a compiled language like C#. Since you're so new, you should really read about how programming (and probably C#) works before just trying to run something.

Answer (score 3):

To run C# code, you'll probably need an IDE for writing and running it. A good, free one is [Microsoft's Visual Studio Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/visual-studio-homepage-vs.aspx) (the free version). Notepad++ is only a text editor, and cannot run code, and is not a great option for writing it, either.

Furthermore, this code will not take a list of strings. It's only the code to split a single string at a certain point. Before you try to make things run in C#, you should understand the basics of the language/programming in general. May I suggest you find either a tutorial on C# if you're familar with the structure and form of code, or if not, try to learn that first?

Comment: The biggest question for me (which no one has even mentioned) is **Where is 'the list of words'?** If it is in Notepad++ then a RegEx replacement should suffice.

Comment: How do I change it so that it includes a certain list of strings?

Comment: @Jeeped I'm not sure that matters too much, to be honest. His code wouldn't be able to split a list from any source, it only takes one string, and splits it at a set index.

Comment: @JoshuaN I feel like you're not listening. Do you want to learn programming, or do you just want to do this task? Because if it's the second, grabbing code off the internet is probably not the best way to go, since it requires you to go through a process for the code to actually do anything.

Comment: A RegEx based Find and Replace should be able to do this in Notepad++. I'm just too rusty on what needs to be a well designed RegEx mask to offer specifics.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code is from C#. As other's pointed out, Notepad++ is a text editor. It can help your write the code, but you can't compile them. When you come back after learning how to code, how to execute it and what an array is,here's one way of doing what you are looking for. It may not be the best though.

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] stringArray = { "text1", "testtest", "test1test2", "test2text1" };
            var length=0;
            var half=0;
            var firstHalf="";
            var secondHalf="";

            foreach (string x in stringArray)
            {
                length = x.Length;
                half = (int) Math.Ceiling(length/2.0);
                firstHalf = x.Substring(0, half);
                secondHalf = x.Substring(half, length - half);
                Debug.WriteLine(firstHalf+" "+secondHalf);

            }
        }
    }
}
```